# Visual studio developer edition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am learning MVC myself. I downloaded visual studio community edition 2013 but it is expired after 30 days.

Can anyone suggest me any Visual studio developer edition without trial period.

Kindly suggest me any websites/url to learn MVC quickly.

Comment: The Community Edition doesn't expire - or shouldn't, anyway. Are you sure it wasn't just prompting you to register (for free)? Admittedly I'd suggest using VS2015 instead...

Comment: Does VS2015 community edition has any trial period?

Comment: No - like VS2013... you may well need to register, but it's still free.

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet. If you would have put your comment in the answer section then I would select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can download Visual Studio 2015 Community, and it's free for individuals. Check this [page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) for more information and download.

I recommend you the [official page](http://www.asp.net/mvc). You can follow the tutorials and have a good learning about ASP.NET and MVC.

I also recommend [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/) for video tutorials. It's paid but you can get a 10 days trial.

Hope it can help you!